# rpmbuild - download files during prescriptlet

Tags: maven, rpmbuild

I'm using the rpm-maven-plugin to build an rpm install of my app.

As part of the rpm install I want to deploy a few tools to the machine that installs the rpm.  The downloads are tar files and I want to unzip it to a specific location as part of the post-install steps.

During the prepare step (`%pre`) I'm downloading a few tools via the `prepareScriptlet` tag :

```
wget some-url-tool1 -O ${rpm.info.downloads_dir}/tool1.tar.gz
wget some-url-tool2 -O ${rpm.info.downloads_dir}/tool2.tar.gz
wget some-url-tool3 -O ${rpm.info.downloads_dir}/tool3.tar.gz
```

I added to the mapping the downloads dir :

```
                <mapping>
                    <directory>${rpm.info.install_dir}/rpms</directory>
                    <filemode>700</filemode>
                    <sources>
                        <source>
                            <location>${rpm.info.downloads_dir}</location>
                        </source>
                    </sources>
                </mapping>
```

The problem is that the downloads_dir doesn't exist and I need to create it before the spec file is created.  I'm getting the following error because I set the directory in the mapping because it doesn't exist (otherwise I will get other error for unchecked files):

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.2.0:rpm (default-rpm) on project my-project-rpm: Source location /tmp/rpmbuild-downloads does not exist -> [Help 1]

I don't want to download the files to a directory that already exist (`/tmp` for example) and add a specific include tag for every tar file. Any way to create the directory before the spec file is created?

Comment: The prepare script is not intended to be used that way. If those tools needed you should define them as dependency in your rpm ....

Comment: you suggest to install them in a separate rpm ? Then what is the use case of the prepare script ?

Comment: The question is first: What kind of tools are that? If those tools are written on your own yes create their own RPM's...

Comment: The `%pre` is usually needed for source packages which don't have here... https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/

Comment: @khmarbaise source code of 3rd party tools, not created by me. I can just download them (no rpm available..)

Comment: Then create an rpm of it... I would never download within a RPM installation something....

Comment: If I want to wrap that 3rd party tool with rpm, I will need to do the same in a dedicated rpm for that... I will have the same problem